# Error1 Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listbox, addition

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub tvw1_AfterSelect(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs) Handles tvw1.AfterSelect
    Dim MPath As String
    MPath = "D:\VB6_Projects\ChurchPresentation\ChurchPresentation\Bible_TH\Bible1971\"
    Dim str As String
    Dim strArr() As String
    Dim count As Integer
    If tvw1.Nodes(0).Nodes(0).Nodes(0).IsSelected = True Then
        rtbThai.LoadFile(MPath & "genesis1.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
        str = rtbThai.Text
        strArr = str.Split(ChrW(10))
        For count = 0 To strArr.Length - 1
            lstThai1971.Controls.Add(strArr(count))
            'MessageBox.Show(strArr(count))
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

It works if I show the messagebox, buf it doesn’t if I use `lstThai1971.Controls.add(strArr(count))`.

What is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming lstThai1971 is a ListBox of sorts, I expect you want to :

```
 lstThai1971.Items.Add(strArr(count))
```

You could also add the entire array using `AddRange`

```
lstThai1971.Items.AddRange(strArr)
```